# app.setBadgeCount is not working

Tags: javascript, electron

```
app.on('ready', function () {
  let self = this;

  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    x: mainWindowState.x,
    y: mainWindowState.y,
    width: mainWindowState.width,
    height: mainWindowState.height,
    'node-integration': false,
    preload: __dirname + '/vendor/electron_boilerplate/context_menu.js',
  });

  if (process.platform === 'linux') {
    app.getLocale();
    mainWindow.setBadgeCount = 5;
  }
}
```

Why can't I use electron.app.setBadgeCount() ?

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that `setBadgeCount` is a function, not a property, and the second problem is that it's part of the `app` module. What you should be doing is:

```
app.setBadgeCount(5)
```

Comment: app.setBadgeCount(5) have same err. This error show electron.app.setBadgeCount is not a function.

Comment: @VietTruongThanh Can you post all the code in your `main.js` please? And which version of Electron are you using?

Comment: i use electron version 1.4.2, Ubuntu 14.04. when i console.log(app) i recieve this: 
App {
  launcher: 
   { setBadgeCount: undefined,
     getBadgeCount: undefined,
     isCounterBadgeAvailable: undefined,
     isUnityRunning: undefined }. 
This need unity.